# Why does UIFont systemFontOfSize:weight not crash on iOS 8.0?

Tags: sdk, teamcity, compiler-warnings, ios8.2

I'm having a strange issue with conflicting compilers, due to `UIFont` `systemFontOfSize:weight` which is supposedly only available from iOS 8.2.

Locally, I can compile a project that uses the function onto an iPhone 6 running iOS 8.0 and it runs perfectly fine. I can also compile to the 8.1 Simulator with correct results, including weighting.

The issue is that we are using Team City and the line will not compile on the server using the iOS 8.0 SDK. I know the solution is to remove the line, but I'd like to find out why it's not catching the error during a local compile... Was the function available before iOS 8.2 but just as a private API?

Answer (score 8):

This method has been available since iOS 8.0. Apple just exposed the method as public API in 8.2. You can check older runtime headers in iOS 8.0.

On iOS 7.0, this method is not supported, and the `UIFontWeight*` constants do not exist, and your app will crash.

Comment: See here for confirmation:
https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/8.0/PrivateFrameworks/UIFoundation.framework/UIFont.h#L95